# Group Objects within already grouped objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting, duplicates, group-object

I'm trying to prepare a list of files with duplicate names but different extensions. At the same time I'd like to exclude files with the same extension. So far I've created this

```
gci -path "PATH" -recurse -file -erroraction silentlycontinue|
Select @{l='Original Filename';e={$_.PSChildName}},  @{l='Compare Filename';e={$_.BaseName.replace('_','*').replace(' ','*').replace('-','*')}}, @{l="Path";e={$_.PSParentPath.Substring(38,$_.PSParentPath.Length-38)}}, @{l="Link";e={$_.FullName}}, @{l="Extension";e={$_.Extension}}
group -Property 'Compare Filename'|
Where {$_.count -ge 2}|
%{$_.group}|
Export-Csv -Path "PATH" -NoTypeInformation
```

I figured I'd need to group objects within already grouped objects by 'extension' property and discard those groups where 'extension groups' count is less than 2.

Exmaple

```
Include
Name Ext
asd  .pdf
asd  .ppt


Exclude
asd  .pdf
asd  .pdf
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Enumerate all extensions in the group and test if there's more than one, eg. change `Where {$_.count -ge 2}` to `Where {@($_.Group.Extension |Sort -Unique).Count -ge 2}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This is it! Thank you